# C# .NET: Deserialize json tree

Tags: c#, json, tree, json.net

Good evening,

For my specific problem, I have to create a menu (a tree of menus more exactly). Thus, I decided to use Composite Design Pattern with the following structure:

- IMenuComponent (an interface defining some properties and so on)
- Menu (contains a list of IMenuComponent)
- MenuEntry (a leaf)

So, I'll have to navigate through it while knowing the way back up. The obvious answer is having a 'parent' property.

I have the following json tree:

```
{
  "Guid": "08967257-9306-4717-a76a-e1a4f0050505",
  "Parent": null,
  "Title": "Main Menu",
  "Message": "A sample message",
  "Elements": [
    {
      "$type": "Menu",
      "Guid": "26dfca59-9163-4b11-8033-e8ad13f3f5cc",
      "Parent": "08967257-9306-4717-a76a-e1a4f0050505",
      "Title": "Option 1",
      "Message": "Another sample message",
      "Elements": [
        {
          "$type": "MenuEntry",
          "Parent": "26dfca59-9163-4b11-8033-e8ad13f3f5cc",
          "Title": "Entry 1",
          "Message": "Another sample message"
        },
        {
          "$type": "MenuEntry",
          "Parent": "26dfca59-9163-4b11-8033-e8ad13f3f5cc",
          "Title": "Entry 2",
          "Message": "Another sample message"
        },
        {
          "$type": "MenuEntry",
          "Parent": "26dfca59-9163-4b11-8033-e8ad13f3f5cc",
          "Title": "Entry 3",
          "Message": "Another sample message"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$type": "MenuEntry",
      "Parent": "08967257-9306-4717-a76a-e1a4f0050505",
      "Title": "Option 2",
      "Message": "Another sample message"
    }
  ]
}
```

This isn't about the deserialization itself, since that's working as it should.

My problem is that I'll have to access the parents after deserializing the file to a 'Menu' (the root). 
I can think of two ways:

- Find a 'parent' in runtime using its Guid - can be bad performance-wise depending on tree size;
- Add a 'Menu' property to both 'Menu' and 'MenuEntry' classes to store the 'parent' and fill it, by finding the corresponding Guid, after deserializing from json. Basically, I'd put it together as soon as the application starts, preventing the find in runtime. It could be bad performance-wise as well.

What's the way to go? And how should I do it?

As a side note, I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the Guid have any meaning in the application? or is it just part of your serialization logic? If the latter, why have it at all? The tree structure is already inherent in the data; having a second representation of it has little benefit and could be in conflict with the actual structure.

Comment: Even though the tree structure is already inherent in the data (even after the deserialization) the only way to know the 'Parent' is to store an id, which in this case is a Guid. Having a 'Parent' of type 'Menu' would have cyclic reference, which is not possible to serialize in the first place. But, filling that Property after the deserialization is a possibility as stated in my post.

Comment: Actually, in the 2nd option I'd have to go through the whole tree and compare the Guids. Since I'm doing that, I can just store the 'Menu' property on the fly, without the need of Guids. I'll give it a try and post the results later.

Comment: @Apidcloud - Just an FYI: it *is* possible to serialize circular references in Json.Net if you use the [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm) setting.  However, this will cause Json.Net to write out additional `$id` and `$ref` properties to the JSON, which may or may not be acceptable to you.  When you deserialize JSON that has this extra metadata, Json.Net will automatically reconnect all the object references for you.

Comment: I didn't know about that one! Only tried `ReferenceLoopHandling` and it didn't work. Since it's an application asset, I believe it would be ok to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ian Mercer comment actually helped me figure out a simple solution (using the 2nd way described in my post above).

The 2nd way doesn't really rely on Guids. After the deserialize, I can just iterate over each menu collection (as I probably would anyway) and give the reference to the 'parent' directly.

```
private void ConnectTree(Menu menu)
{
    foreach (IMenuComponent component in menu.Elements) {
        if (component is Menu) {
            (component as Menu).ParentMenu = menu;
            ConnectTree (component as Menu);
        } 
        else if (component is MenuEntry) {
            (component as MenuEntry).ParentMenu = menu;
        }
    }
}
```

Just need to call `ConnectTree(_deserializedMenu)`

**Edit:**
@Brian Rogers just mentioned PreserveReferencesHandling property from json net. The original problem was all about json not supporting circular references, but that solves it - it's the same logic as using Guids. There are multiple solutions, which is always good to know.

Thanks!